# Fazer um random de um dataset com pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pandas

Eu estou tentando extrair 15O linhas de um dataset de 500 linhas. So que gostaria de fazê-lo em random.

**Meus dados**

```
objeto,cor,label
cachorro,branco,animal
manga,laranja,fruta
calça,preta,roupa
```

**Meu script**

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('produit_non_conforme.csv', sep = ',')
mails_random = df.sample(150) 

print(mails_random)
```

Mas o resultado é estranhíssimo, eu não tenho a linha completa...

```
         objeto                ...         label
277      uva                   ...         fruta
116      urso                  ...         animal
495      ...                   ...         ...
```

Seria possível ter a linha completa?

Comment: Não é só questão de o `print` ocultar a coluna por espaço? Tente fazer `print(mails_random['cor'])`.

Comment: Infelizmente quando faço isso o print imprime apenas essa coluna cor. E eu preciso das três...

Comment: Tente `print( pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['objeto', 'cor', 'label']) )`

Comment: Acho que esse link aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-how-to-widen-output-display-to-see-more-columns Pode te ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia apenas pegar o [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) do DataFrame e utilizá-lo como bem entender.

Ex.:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('teste.csv', sep = ',')
mails_random = df.sample(2) 

for linha in mails_random.values:
    print(linha)  # ['coluna_1', 'coluna_2', 'coluna_3']
```

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/ShowySpitefulSyntax) com o código funcionando

Answer (score 1):

Então. Suponha que você queira selecionar dois indexes aleatórios em uma data_frame de 4  linhas.

você pode prosseguir da seguinte forma:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,2,3,4]})

df_index = list(df.index)

indexs = np.random.choice(df_index,2)

new_df = df.iloc[indexs]
```

Espero ter ajudado